# GitHub Pages failed to build your site: Struggling to troubleshoot vague error message

Tags: github, error-handling, jekyll, github-pages

After being idle for a while, I recently attempted to make several (basic text) content changes in a website I built using Jekyll and GitHub. I pushed changes from my terminal (and did not receive any errors)

However, I noticed website did not update and saw the telling "x" marks next to the commits. Upon investigating the reasons for the failed commit, I simply receive a vague error message ([here](https://github.com/mdrs228/mdrs228.github.io/runs/2002965993)): "GitHub Pages failed to build your site. Page build failed."

I searched for common reasons for vague Jekyll build errors for GitHub Pages ([here](https://docs.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/troubleshooting-jekyll-build-errors-for-github-pages-sites#troubleshooting-build-errors)):

```
- You're using unsupported plugins. For more information, see "About GitHub Pages and Jekyll."
- Your repository has exceeded our repository size limits. For more information, see "What is my disk quota?"
- You changed the source setting in your _config.yml file. GitHub Pages overrides this setting during the build process.
- A filename in your publishing source contains a colon (:) which is not supported.
```

I do not think I am using unsupported plugins (since I have not added any plugins after the page was working/updatable months ago). I do not think I have exceeded the repository size limits. And I checked that the `_config.yml` file did not have any errors using `YAML Validator`. I also do not think the filename contains a colon (:).

This leaves me feeling stumped on how to determine the problem. Admittedly, I am unsure how to check the "source setting" in my `_config.yml` file (if that could be the problem source). What other common issues could cause this problem?

Thank you for sharing any suggestions!